# Autocomplete lombok with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, lombok

I don't know if this is a bug or misconfiguration in eclipse with lombok. Eclipse recognizes all annotations but when I try to use:

```
val list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

list only hace Object methods eclipse can't infer ArrayList methods as size() isEmpty() etc etc

How could I configure lombok for autocomplete?

I'm using eclipse STS 4.19 and eclipse 2023-06 with same result with val and var

Comment: @howlger I'm using STS 4.19 and 2023-06 with same results with var and val

Comment: @howlger Lombok makes `val` valid as a local variable type

Comment: @JacoboGeada Do other Lombok features such as `@Getter` and `@Data` work with Eclipse autocompletion? If not, you probably just need to install the Lombok plugin.

Comment: You have yet to mention which version of *Lombok* this is, and Java, which would seem important. Then again, maybe you could use the standard `var` identifier instead of relying on Lombok for this at development and runtime.

Comment: @nitind i have used several versions of lombok with same results

Comment: Several versions sounds like trial and error and is not what you were asked for. It seems the following known Lombok issue (which also provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which is lacking in this question): https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3440

Answer (score 1):

This is a **known issue** of Lombok that is [being worked on](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3440#issuecomment-1680052861):

[**Lombok issue #3440**: [BUG] Autocomplete for `val` variables stops working "randomly" in Eclipse](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3440)